# Como abrir um arquivo de relatório no formato RDF?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me enviaram um relatório com a extensão .rdf. O sistema que gerou este relatório utiliza o MS SQL server 2008 como SGBD.

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para visualizar e manipular as informações deste arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

[RDF-Gravity](http://semweb.salzburgresearch.at/apps/rdf-gravity/index.html) Pode ser usada para abrir esse tipo de arquivo.

Comment: Você conseguiu utilizar esse programa? aqui ele não instala, dá um erro no Java ("Entrada não assinada no recurso...").

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço `.RDF` tão bem assim, mas acho que [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) consegue abrir um relatório com essa extensão.